# merge array items specific array items

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I got this array:

```
array (
  0 => 'K.',
  1 => 'Vrachtschip',
  2 => 'L.',
  3 => 'Gevechtsschip',
  4 => 'Z.',
  5 => 'Gevechtsschip',
  6 => 'Kruiser',
  7 => 'Slagschip',
  8 => 'Bommenwerper',
  9 => 'Vernietiger',
  10 => 'Interceptor.',
)
```

of can I merge the items `[0]` with `[1]`, because K. vrachtschip must be together.
same ass `[2]` and `[3]`; and `[4]` with `[5]`. if there is 1 letter and then a dot (k.) it must be merged with the following array item.

Anyone that can help me :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$arr = array ( 
    'K.',
    'Vrachtschip',
    'L.',
    'Gevechtsschip',
    'Z.',
    'Gevechtsschip',
    'Kruiser',
    'Slagschip',
    'Bommenwerper',
    'Vernietiger',
    'Interceptor',
    'B.',
);

$concat = '';
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $elem) {
    if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]\.$/', $elem)) {
        $concat = $elem;
        continue;
    }
    $result[] = $concat.$elem;
    $concat = '';
}
if ($concat) $result[] = $concat;
print_r($result);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => K.Vrachtschip
    [1] => L.Gevechtsschip
    [2] => Z.Gevechtsschip
    [3] => Kruiser
    [4] => Slagschip
    [5] => Bommenwerper
    [6] => Vernietiger
    [7] => Interceptor
    [8] => B.
)
```

Comment: +1 Good one. However, you run the risk of discarding initials if last in array (may never be the case) or there are several in a row (again, may not be relevant) ([demo](http://www.ideone.com/clone/UQeZ6))

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a regular expression to test all entries of your array. 
If an occurence is founded, concat the value of your entrie with the next.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do the following (pseudo code):

1. Create empty array for result
2. Iterate the original array
3. For each value: does it match `/^[a-z]\.$/i`?
4. If yes, see if original array contains a next element?
5. If yes, concatenate the two items and add to resulting array, skip next item in loop
6. If no (pt. 4 or 5) add directly to resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
for($idx=0, $max = count($array_in); $idx < $max; $idx++)
{
   if(preg_match('/^[a-z]\.$/i', $array_in[$idx]))
   {
      $array_out[] = $array_in[$idx].$array_in[$idx+1];
      $idx++;
   }
   else
   {
      $array_out[] = $array_in[$idx];
   }

}
```